# DateTime.TryParseExact Erratic results

Tags: c#, datetime

Using the below DateTime.TryPaseExact method gives me different out puts when one is expected.

I get the following formats returned from the code below:

```
2014-02-10 18:32:37
1402-10-18 17:23:00 (which is clearly incorrect)
```

How do I just get a `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format returned?

```
static readonly string[] DateFormats = new string[] { "yyMMddHHmm", "yyyyMMddHHmm", "yyMMddHHmmss", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" };

DateTime date;                                    
DateTime.TryParseExact("140211090915", DateFormats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                               DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out date);
```

Also if someone could explain why this `140211084947` input returns the expected format and `140211090915` returns an unwanted format I would be grateful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is clear that you are mistaken.

When the format is `yyMMddHHmmss`, it is taking first `2` digits as a year which in this case is `14` and is automatically converted to `2014`.

When format is something like `yyyy....`, it is taking first `4` digits as a year which in your case is `1402`.

From [`The "yy" Custom Format Specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#yySpecifier)

> In a parsing operation, a two-digit year that is parsed using the "yy"
>   custom format specifier is interpreted based on the
>   `Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax` property of the format provider's current
>   calendar.

From [`Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> This property allows a 2-digit year to be properly translated to a
>   4-digit year. **For example, if this property is set to 2029, the
>   100-year range is from 1930 to 2029. Therefore, a 2-digit value of 30
>   is interpreted as 1930, while a 2-digit value of 29 is interpreted as
>   2029.**

As Marcin *[mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695481/datetime-tryparseexact-erratic-results#comment32801096_21695548)*, your string input doesn't match with `yyMMddHHmm` and `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` formats.

Your `140211084947` string matches with `yyMMddHHmmss` format but it doesn't match with `yyyyMMddHHmm` format (Because `49` is not a valid hour)

Comment: Neither `yyMMddHHmm` nor `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` matches the input string

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Yes, you are right. But it matches with `yyMMddHHmmss` and `yyyyMMddHHmm` format. From [`DateTime.TryParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) _The format of the string representation must match_ **at least one of the specified formats exactly.**

Comment: Your answer doesn't quite cover why it sometimes chooses one format, and sometimes the other, which would appear to be because in the case of the 140211090915 value, the "0915" is a valid time, do matches the first pattern, whereas for 140211084947, "4947" is not, so a subsequent pattern is tried.

Comment: @Iridium When I wrote this answer (in first revision of the question) OP have only `140211090915` as an _input string_. I think he add it (`140211084947`) so quickly to his question, it doesn't even affect it to [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21695481/revisions). You have a point of course, `4947` doesn't match with `HHmm` format but it matches with `mmss` format (Added it to my answer). That's why `DateTime.TryParseExact` doesn't fail in this case.

Comment: Soner is correct about me adding the additional input string quckly after creating the question. I was not aware the sequence of the formats was important but it is after some testing (thank you @Iridium)